# Write section sign or section mark in the data file in Linux

Tags: java, java-io

I want to write the section sign symbol in the dat file in Linux. the below code works fine in windows. But getting additional special character when executed in Linux env.

```
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(xyz.dat, true),  Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
output.append("§");
```

The same code executed in Linux shows the result as Â§

Comment: What Linux tool are you using to display the result?  Most likely that tool or the terminal on which it is being displayed is not set to UTF-8.

Comment: It's Linux 2.6.18-418.el5 x86_64 and the charset set is UTF-8
    bash-3.2$ echo $LANG
    en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Are you attempting to display the file in a terminal?  Which terminal? Does the terminal program support UTF-8?

Comment: @JimGarrison, Using putty to connect to the terminal. I dont think the terminal support is required.

Comment: I would suggest you compare the output files from Windows and Linux. see if they are identical then you know the problem is only in the display

Comment: On the contrary, it is the TERMINAL that takes the byte stream and  displays the data, and putty must be configured to support UTF-8. See https://serverfault.com/questions/475925/how-to-fix-putty-showing-garbled-characters

Comment: @JimGarrison
Just downloaded the file to windows and checked, its showing the same special char in the notepad 926**Â§** and the encoding set in the notepad is 1252 (ANSI  - Latin I). If I change the encode to UTF-8, the output is perfect.
Anyhow in the code, I have mentioned as UTF-8.

Comment: That supports my statement that you need to adjust putty's configuration to support UTF-8 display.

Comment: @JimGarrison
Thanks Jim, When checked the putty config, its shows ISO--8859, I just changed it to UTF-8, and the output shows perfect now.
Thanks Jim

Comment: Please do not use [java-ee] tag as long as problem is already demonstrable using a plain Java application class with main() method. Thank you.